# Different alignment in Visual Studio Code and BitBucket

Tags: editor, bitbucket, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code on my Ubuntu box and when I checked in my code into BitBucket, somehow they are in different alignment, see below.

[image]

What would have caused this and how to I rectify this?

Comment: You undoubtedly have a mixture of tabs and spaces (and your two environments are set up with different tab stops). You can set them to the same tab stop size (can be non-trivial) or convert the files to indent the same way throughout (e.g., convert all the tabs to spaces).

Comment: my visual studio code has this setting now   "editor.tabSize": 4 I believe BitBucket has tabsize as 4, too?

Comment: The normal VS has both "tabify" and "untabify". Using either one will typically eliminate this particular problem. Not sure if VS.C has this though.

Comment: thanks @jerry, I just realized that there are mixed tabs and spaces in the beginning of those lines. Will you please put your comments as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code almost certainly contains both tabs and spaces for indentation.

When this happens, almost any difference in how tabs are rendered will lead to anomalies such as you've shown above--code that looks right in one rendering looks all wrong in another.

Most code editors include ways to convert the entire file to using either spaces or tabs, but not a combination of the two. Using only spaces probably does the most to guarantee that the code will look the same, regardless of the environment.

On the other hand, using only tabs means that each user will probably see the code as s/he normally views code (at least assuming s/he has his/her environment set up to deal with tabs). For example, if the code is indented with tabs, and you like indentation to be by 8 spaces, but I prefer 4 spaces, each of us can get exactly that from identical source code (i.e., most editors will let us set the tab stops as we see fit).

Answer (score 2):

Select the whole document or the line you have problem with,
Then go to `Edit -> Advanced -> Tabify Selected Lines`

That should fixed the issue. More info : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/03/14/how-to-convert-tabs-to-spaces-and-vice-versa/